MUI X Week Picker with custom Date Field
I'm working on a Week picker based on MUI X official documentation :
https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-calendar/#week-picker
This works quite well, except that the input displays the click date as the value. In my case, I'd like the input to display the week number of the year with the year as the value. I don't know if this is possible, as the input props expects a date.

What I want :  week 43 - 2023
Current component code
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { isSameWeek } from 'date-fns';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { PickersDay, PickersDayProps } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/PickersDay';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

interface CustomPickerDayProps extends PickersDayProps<Date> {
  isSelected: boolean;
  isHovered: boolean;
}

const CustomPickersDay = styled(PickersDay, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'isSelected' && prop !== 'isHovered',
})<CustomPickerDayProps>(({ theme, isSelected, isHovered, day }) => ({
  borderRadius: 0,
  ...(isSelected && {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
    '&:hover, &:focus': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
  }),
  ...(isHovered && {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary[theme.palette.mode],
    '&:hover, &:focus': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary[theme.palette.mode],
    },
  }),
  ...(day.getDay() === 1 && {
    borderTopLeftRadius: '50%',
    borderBottomLeftRadius: '50%',
  }),
  ...(day.getDay() === 0 && {
    borderTopRightRadius: '50%',
    borderBottomRightRadius: '50%',
  }),
})) as React.ComponentType<CustomPickerDayProps>;

const isInSameWeek = (dayA: Date, dayB: Date | null | undefined) => {
  if (dayB == null) {
    return false;
  }
  return isSameWeek(dayA, dayB, { weekStartsOn: 1 });
};

function Day(
  props: PickersDayProps<Date> & {
    selectedDay?: Date | null;
    hoveredDay?: Date | null;
  },
) {
  const { day, selectedDay, hoveredDay, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <CustomPickersDay
      {...other}
      day={day}
      sx={{ px: 2.5 }}
      disableMargin
      selected={false}
      isSelected={isInSameWeek(day, selectedDay)}
      isHovered={isInSameWeek(day, hoveredDay)}
    />
  );
}

export default function WeekCalendar({ onChange }: { onChange: (newValue: Date | null) => void }) {
  const [hoveredDay, setHoveredDay] = useState<Date | null>(null);
  const [value, setValue] = useState<Date | null>(new Date('2022-04-17'));

  const theme = useTheme();

  const handleDateChange = (newValue: Date | null) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    onChange(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <DatePicker
      value={value}
      onChange={handleDateChange}
      showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth
      displayWeekNumber
      slots={{ day: Day }}
      slotProps={{
        day: (ownerState) =>
          ({
            selectedDay: value,
            hoveredDay,
            onPointerEnter: () => setHoveredDay(ownerState.day),
            onPointerLeave: () => setHoveredDay(null),
          } as any),
      }}
      sx={{
        marginTop: '12px',
        marginRight: '20px',
        '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
          padding: '5px',
          color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
          fontSize: '14px',
        },
        '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
          color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
          width: '20px',
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}

As an alternative approach, I've tried using format and the “w” option, which according to date-fns should give the number of the week in the year, but it doesn't work.
If you have any ideas, I'd love to hear from you.

The solution depends on the date library you choose alongside the date picker. If the date library provides a format for the week number, it simplifies things. Otherwise, you'll need to calculate the week number within the component and pass it accordingly.
For example, if you are using dayjs, its documentation shows that the week of the year number is available as an advanced format. which means, you cannot use it directly like YYYY for the year(or other simple available formats) and it must be used with dayjs().format.
In this case, you can add an attribute to the DatePicker with the name format (provided by the MUI DatePicker but it will work according to the dateAdapter) and use the week of the year format:
import dayjs from "dayjs";

{...rest of your code}
<DatePicker
  value={value}
  format={`week ${dayjs(value).format("ww")} - YYYY`}
  {...rest of your params}
/>

if the date library does not provide the week number format, you can calculate the week number based on the selected date value and use it in the format attribute like this
{...rest of your code}

const weekNumber:number = calculateWeekNumber(value);

{...rest of your code}

<DatePicker
  value={value}
  format={`week ${weekNumber} - YYYY`}
  {...rest of your params}
/>


This is a good workaround, but it doesn't do everything, because if no character is interpreted by the date picker format, then it doesn't display anything, even if there is text. So in your example, if there are no years, it displays empty text.
However, there's a problem with your example: you need to put single quotes around the text week so that the characters aren't interpreted.  Unless it's not a problem with Date fns?
So here the right code in my case with date fns :
format={'Week “ ${format(dateValue, ”w ’)} yyyy}
